# Corollary of Baire theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, baire-category

Can anybody help me to prove the following result?

Corollary of Baire theorem: Let $(K_j)_{j>0}$ be an increasing sequence of compact sets in $C^n$ and $X$ a bounded open set such that $\overline X\subset\cup K_j.$ Then for every $x\in X$ there is $J>0$ so that $x\in int(K_J).$

Comment: So you want to prove that if $X \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty K_n$ then $X \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \operatorname{Int}(K_n)$. Can you determine what is in $\left ( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty K_n \right ) \setminus \left ( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \operatorname{Int}(K_n) \right )$? In particular is this set closed? open? hollow? dense?

Comment: We may assume that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}K_n$ is compact hence $(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}K_n)\setminus(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} int(K_n))$ is compact.

Comment: Why should $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty K_n$ be compact? Consider $X=\mathbb{C}^m$ and $K_n=\overline{B(0,n)}$. This one shows the union needn't be bounded. It also needn't be closed: consider $K_n=\overline{B(0,1-1/n)}$.

Comment: We may assume that $X$ is bounded and its closure is in $\bigcup_n K_n$ then replace each $K_n$ by $\overline X\cap K_n.$

Comment: Why can you assume any of that? Is that given? Or are you instead decomposing $X$ in some manner (e.g. using separability)?

Comment: Yes, it is given.

Comment: Then please include it in the problem statement.

Comment: Could you please glance the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can anybody check whether this proof answers correctly the problem above?

For $j>0$ set $C_j=\mathbb{C}^m\setminus Int(\bigcup_{n=1}^j K_n)$  note that  $C_j$ is closed and contains  $\mathbb{C}^m\setminus K_j$ (because $K_j=\bigcup_n^j K_{n}$ since the sequence is increasing).

Let $x\in X$ we will prove by contradiction that $x\in Int(K_{j_0})$ for some $j_0>0.$ Suppose that $K_j$ does not contain any open ball centered at $x$, for any $j.$ This means that any open ball $B$ centered at $x,$  contains a point from $\mathbb{C}^m\setminus K_j$ in other  word  for all $j>0$ and $r>0$  the set $B(x,r)\setminus K_j$ is non-empty. That means for all $j>0$ there is $x_j\in\mathbb{C}^m$ so that $x_j\in B(x, 1/j)\setminus K_j.$

Remark that the sequence $(x_j)_j$ converges to $x$ and all its subsequences also converge to $x.$ As the sequence $(K_j)_j$ is increasing then for $j$ fix the point $x_n$ does not belong to $K_j$ for all $n\geq j$ that means $x_n\in C_j$  for all $n\geq j$ by closedness,  the limit $x$ of the subsequence $(x_n)_{n>j}$ belongs to $C_j$ this for all $j>0$ in other word $x\in \cap^{\infty}_{j=1} C_j.$ That means $x\not\in Int(\bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1} K_n)$ then $x\not\in X,$ a contradiction hence there is $n_0>0$ so that $B(x, 1/n_0)\subset K_{n_0}$ that gives $x\in Int(K_{n_0})$.